# Unable to get local Magento install to work after importing database

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin

I recently created a database backup of the live site to use to import locally. After importing database dump, and trying to run the Magento install locally, I get many errors in the log that are preventing me from moving forward and I have no idea where to start.

Here is a copy of the log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:96:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'us_magento.log_visitor' doesn't exist";i:1;s:3018:"#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)

2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)

4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)

5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)

6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor', Array)

7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))

8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()

9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))

10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))

11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)

12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)

13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()

14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()

15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')

16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

17 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

18 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

19 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite/index.php(94): Mage::run('', 'store')

20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:21:"/mySite/";s:11:"script_name";s:30:"/mySite/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clear enough, the table `us_magento.log_visitor` is missing.
You either have an issue with your DB dump that didn't bring all the tables or you have a configuration problem on your local Magento installation.

Check your local database after the import and look for the table `log_visitor`.
Also, check your Magento `local.xml` file that you can find inside the folder `MAGENTO_ROOT/app/etc`.
Check the DB configurations on the `local.xml` file and ensure that you are using the same DB name `us_magento`.